# How to force test program to be linked to static library built by libtool

Tags: c, autotools, static-linking, libtool

I have a library managed by autotools. I have the following line in the `Makefile.am`, as well as other necessary configurations

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libstuff.la
```

My project also builds a program to run some test suites. This program is configured as follows:

```
noinst_PROGRAMS = runtests
runtests_SOURCES = test/stuff.c stuff.h
runtests_LDADD = libstuff.la
```

However, the program is always linked to the dynamic version of `libstuff.la`, which complicates some situations (for example, debugging with `gdb`). How could I force the program to be linked against `libstuff.a` instead of `libstuff.so` or equivalent dynamic library?

Comment: Debugging is not complicated. You just have to remember to prefix everything with `libtool --mode=execute`. For gdb that means: `libtool --mode=execute gdb runtests`. Simple as that.

Comment: @jørgensen this seems to be a good solution but did not worked here. I ran `libtool --mode=execute gdb runtests`  and got
`libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --mode=execute`. Using `i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1` in Mac OS and autotools 2.61.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right way to do this is to add the `-static` flag to an `LDFLAGS` variable.
For all targets: `AM_LDFLAGS = -static`

Or specifically for the test program: `runtests_LDFLAGS = -static`

Comment: Good one! This renders my answer unnecessary.

Comment: I've tried this, but it seems to have no effect -- I add this, autoreconf, clean and rebuild, but everything is still linked dynamically.  I tried -all-static as well, but it similarly has no effect...

Comment: @ChrisDodd - do you mean external dynamic libraries are still being used? Or completely self-contained libraries within the package itself? e.g. automake's `-static` option isn't going to help if you rely on an external `libpng` for example.

Comment: External libraries are still linked dynamically, even if static libs are available.